# Can't make a hitbox for my Ping Pong pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Here's my script, it need to make a hitbox so the ball bounce off the thing. It's a very basic ping pong game. I have tried with coordinates and tried watching other videos and forums, I'd really appreciate of someone could help me. I simply don't understand, it's a school assignment. Ik it's lazy, but could someone please make a collision box for me. Or at least help me.

Here's the script:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

width = 500
height = 400
#pygame.title("Ping Pong Level 1")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
y = 30
g = 30
x = 40
f = 100
velxX = 2
velfF = 2
velX = 50
velF = 20

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (30, y, 30, 100))
    player1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (440, g, 30, 100))
    line = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 0, 10, 400))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()


    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_w] and y > 0:
        y -= 5
    if pressed[pygame.K_s] and y < height - 100:
        y += 5
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP] and g > 0:
        g -= 5
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and g < height - 100:
        g += 5


    velF += velfF
    velX += velxX

    if velF < 0 or velF > height - 5:
        velfF *= -1
    if velX < 0 or velX > width - 5:
        velxX *= -1

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), (velX, velF), 5)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

    draw()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pygame/Tom%27s_Pong

Comment: Collision is a big subject ... you have to understand how it works first. Maybe easier there : https://inventwithpython.com/chapter18.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I am experementing with coordinates and stuff, but I am soon giving up.

Comment: But could you help me implement it into my script please?

Comment: You have to try by yourself ... Stackoverflow's users help, not write code for you.

Comment: Could you help me get started? I littarly have no clue on what any off that is.

Comment: Really all is written in both references ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's walk through this step for step.

First, let's reorder your code so we have a nice standard main loop of `event handling -> state update -> draw`. We see that you have a `draw` function, but you don't draw everything in this function. Also, you call `pygame.display.flip()` before `draw`. `screen.mainloop()` doen't make sense, and `sys.exit()` will also not work because you don't import `sys`.

Step 1:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()

    width = 500
    height = 400
    #pygame.title("Ping Pong Level 1")
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    y = 30
    g = 30
    x = 40
    f = 100
    velxX = 2
    velfF = 2
    velX = 50
    velF = 20

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                return

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_w] and y > 0:
            y -= 5
        if pressed[pygame.K_s] and y < height - 100:
            y += 5
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP] and g > 0:
            g -= 5
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and g < height - 100:
            g += 5

        velF += velfF
        velX += velxX

        if velF < 0 or velF > height - 5:
            velfF *= -1
        if velX < 0 or velX > width - 5:
            velxX *= -1

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), (velX, velF), 5)
        player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (30, y, 30, 100))
        player1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (440, g, 30, 100))
        line = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 0, 10, 400))
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Next, let's look at your game state and drawing. You have a bunch of variables with strange names, and variables you don't use or don't make sense (like `velxX`, `f`, or `player1`) You also draw some rects, so let's fix thing up with using a proper data structures: the helpful [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) and [`Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) classes.

Step 2:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    left_paddle = pygame.Rect((30, 30, 30, 100))
    right_paddle = pygame.Rect((440, 30, 30, 100))

    ball_position = pygame.Vector2((50, 20))
    ball_direction = pygame.Vector2((1, 1)).normalize()
    ball_speed = 5

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                return

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: left_paddle.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: left_paddle.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: right_paddle.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: right_paddle.move_ip(0, 5)

        # keep paddles on the screen
        left_paddle.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
        right_paddle.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

        ball_position += ball_direction * ball_speed

        # flip direction on edge
        if ball_position[1] < 0 or ball_position[1] > screen_rect.height - 5:
            ball_direction = pygame.Vector2(ball_direction[0], -ball_direction[1])

        if ball_position[0] < 0 or ball_position[0] > screen_rect.width - 5:
            ball_direction = pygame.Vector2(-ball_direction[0], ball_direction[1])

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), left_paddle)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), right_paddle)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 0, 10, 400))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), [int(v) for v in ball_position], 5)
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

So far, so good. Now implementing the collision detection is easy. We could calculate where the ball would be in the next step, and then check if they would collide with a paddle. Since we're using the [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) class, it's easy to check for collision ([`collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint)) and to make them bigger ([`inflate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate), because the size of the ball is bigger than one pixel).

Step 3:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    left_paddle = pygame.Rect((30, 30, 30, 100))
    right_paddle = pygame.Rect((440, 30, 30, 100))

    ball_position = pygame.Vector2((150, 120))
    ball_direction = pygame.Vector2((1, 1)).normalize()
    ball_speed = 5

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                return

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: left_paddle.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: left_paddle.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: right_paddle.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: right_paddle.move_ip(0, 5)

        # keep paddles on the screen
        for paddle in (left_paddle, right_paddle):
            paddle.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

        ball_position += ball_direction * ball_speed

        # flip direction on edge
        if ball_position[1] < 0 or ball_position[1] > screen_rect.height - 5:
            ball_direction = pygame.Vector2(ball_direction[0], -ball_direction[1])

        if ball_position[0] < 0 or ball_position[0] > screen_rect.width - 5:
            ball_direction = pygame.Vector2(-ball_direction[0], ball_direction[1])

        next_ball_position = ball_position + ball_direction * ball_speed
        for paddle in (left_paddle, right_paddle):
            if paddle.inflate(5, 5).collidepoint(next_ball_position):
                ball_direction = pygame.Vector2(-ball_direction[0], ball_direction[1])

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        for paddle in (left_paddle, right_paddle):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), paddle)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 0, 10, 400))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), [int(v) for v in ball_position], 5)
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Note that this works only if the ball hits the paddle at the front, but you could easily check the ball position relative to the paddle to determine if you want to change the ball direction's `y` or `x` axis.

And since we're using a vector for the ball's direction, it's also easy to let the ball move in angles other than 45°.

Comment: Thank you so much for going through everything. Like you have no idea xD You are really smart and a good teacher